# binding rows from a function into a dataframe

Tags: r

I wrote a function that does operations on a list. Now I am trying to bind the results into a `data.frame`, but nothing seems to work. Can someone explain how to fix this, but more importantly, why I am having this problem?

```
ret<-lapply(1:3,function(x){getVals(x,x+1,x+2)})

getVals<-function(x,y,z){
rbind(x,y,z)    
}

as.data.frame(ret)
as.matrix(ret,ncol=3)
```

Desired output is:

```
1,2,3
2,3,4
3,4,5
```

Comment: Try `do.call(cbind, ret)` and that should work. And, you can wrap that with `as.data.frame` to get a data frame instead of a matrix you constructed.

Comment: That was what I needed (although it was actually cbind). Thanks!

Comment: Can't you use `c` instead of `rbind` in `getVals`? That would make things easier. Or you can use  `sapply` instead of `lapply` and get a matrix as a result: `sapply(1:3, function(x) getVals(x, x+1, x+2))`

Comment: @Gopala, maybe you can turn it into an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the result as a data frame by doing something like this:

```
as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, ret))
  V1 V2 V3
x  1  2  3
y  2  3  4
z  3  4  5
```

Answer (score 0):

ret is a list of arrays.  The are several ways of working with a these lists.  I prefer to unlist, convert to matrix and then onto the data frame:

```
df<-data.frame(matrix(unlist(ret),ncol=3, byrow=TRUE))
df
```